# cifar10 randomize train and test set

Tags: python, numpy, random, keras, numpy-ndarray

I would like to randomize the 60000 observations of the CIFAR-10 dataset present in the *keras.datasets* library. I know that it may not be so relevant in order to construct a neural network, but I'm a Python novice and I would like to learn data handling with this programming language.

So, to import the dataset, I run

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

which automatically gives me a default subdivision of the train and test set; but I would like to mix them. 
The steps I have in mind are:

- concatenate the train and test sets in a dataset *X* of shape (60000, 32, 32, 3) and a dataset *Y* of shape (60000, 1)
- generate some random indeces to subset the *X* and *Y* dataset in, say, a training set of 50000 obs and a test set of 10000 obs
- create new datasets (in a *ndarray* format) *X_train*, *X_test*, *Y_train*, *Y_test* with the same shapes as the original ones, so that I can start training my convolutional neural network

but maybe there's even a quicker approach to this.

I have tried different methods for a couple of hours but I didn't manage to achieve anything. Can somebody help me? I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to split the data.  If you want to use the same randomized index selection each time you run the code, you can set the `random_state` value and you will have the same test/train split each time.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

# View first image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Concatenate train and test images
X = np.concatenate((X_train,X_test))
y = np.concatenate((Y_train,Y_test))

# Check shape
print(X.shape) # (60000, 32, 32, 3)

# Split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=10000, random_state=1234)

# Check shape
print(X_train.shape) # (50000, 32, 32, 3)

# View first image
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very helpful for a newbie like me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete demo as you requested. First we download the data and randomize them once and then take first 50K for training and the remaining 10K for validation purposes.

```
In [21]: import tensorflow  
In [22]: import tensorflow.keras.datasets as datasets    
In [23]: cifar10 = datasets.cifar10.load_data() 
In [24]: (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data() 

In [25]: X_train.shape, Y_train.shape 
Out[25]: ((50000, 32, 32, 3), (50000, 1))

In [26]: X_test.shape, Y_test.shape 
Out[26]: ((10000, 32, 32, 3), (10000, 1)) 

In [27]: import numpy as np
In [28]: X, Y = np.vstack((X_train, X_test)), np.vstack((Y_train, Y_test))  

In [29]: X.shape, Y.shape 
Out[29]: ((60000, 32, 32, 3), (60000, 1)) 

In [30]: # Shuffle only the training data along axis 0 
    ...: def shuffle_train_data(X_train, Y_train): 
    ...:     """called after each epoch""" 
    ...:     perm = np.random.permutation(len(Y_train)) 
    ...:     Xtr_shuf = X_train[perm] 
    ...:     Ytr_shuf = Y_train[perm] 
    ...:      
    ...:     return Xtr_shuf, Ytr_shuf 


In [31]: X_shuffled, Y_shuffled = shuffle_train_data(X, Y) 

In [32]: (X_train_new, Y_train_new) = X_shuffled[:50000, ...], Y_shuffled[:50000, ...] 

In [33]: (X_test_new, Y_test_new) = X_shuffled[50000:, ...], Y_shuffled[50000:, ...] 

In [34]: X_train_new.shape, Y_train_new.shape 
Out[34]: ((50000, 32, 32, 3), (50000, 1))

In [35]: X_test_new.shape, Y_test_new.shape 
Out[35]: ((10000, 32, 32, 3), (10000, 1))
```

---

We have a function `shuffle_train_data` which consistently shuffles the data keeping the examples and their labels in the same order.